# passing data from a form to php

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox

Despite this is a common subject, haven't found the answer after a while searching.

I have this html in my view:

```
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label">Tipo de Socio</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox line">
        <input type="checkbox" id="registered" value="registered" name="type[]" /> Registrado
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox line">
        <input type="checkbox" value="notregistered" name="type[]"/> Pre-Registrado
      </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see, the information captured from the input is sended to an array, which ouput is:

```
  array (size=2)
  0 => string 'u.status = 2' (length=12)
  1 => string 'u.status = 1' (length=12)
```

what i want to achieve is to name the subkey with a descriptive name, like:

```
  array (size=2)
  registered => string 'u.status = 2' (length=12)
  notregistered => string 'u.status = 1' (length=12)
```

shall i send this subkey names directly from the html, or should i make a function in php to do this?

Comment: yes, i am asking if i can name the key from the inside array from the html form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label">Tipo de Socio</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox line">
        <input type="checkbox" id="registered" value="registered" name="type[registered]" /> Registrado
      </label>
      <label class="checkbox line">
        <input type="checkbox" value="notregistered" name="type[notregistered]"/> Pre-Registrado
      </label>
    </div>
</div>
```